# How to find frequency of characters in a string without using array in java

Tags: java, string

Given a String, I want to create a frequency distribution of characters in the String.  That is, for each distinct character in the string, I want to count how many times it occurs.

Output is a `String` that consists of zero or more occurrences of the pattern *xd*, where *x* is a character from the source String, and *d* is the number of occurrences of *x* within the String. Each *x* in the output should occur once.

The challenge is to do this without using an array or `Collection`.

Examples:

```
 Source:  "aasdddr"          Result: "a2s1d3r1"
 Source:  "aabacc"           Result: "a3b1c2"
 Source:  "aasdddraabcdaa"   Result: "a6s1d4r1b1c1"
```

I tried this way:

```
  String str = "aasdddr", result = ""; 
  int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
      result += "" + str.charAt(i);
      for(int j = 1; j < str.length(); j++){
          if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)){
              counter++;
          }
      }
      result += counter;
    }
  System.out.println(result);
```

My output is `a1a2s3d6d9d12r13`

Comment: What would the output be for `String str = "aasdddraabcdaa" ?

Comment: The output of String str = "aasdddraabcdaa" would be a6s1d4r1b1c1.

Comment: I think you should use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) but I guess that if you have not yet learned [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) then you probably can't use `Map`.

Comment: Yes, I don't have any knowledge about array or map. I looked at everywhere, but there isn't any solution without them.

Comment: Are there restrictions on what characters may be in the String? Are digits allowed? Punctuation characters?  If digits are allowed, there is the potential for ambiguities in the result.

Comment: The characters should be letters.

Comment: @NevzatTalhaÖzcan, Your code shows you have the right idea. But, the question is closed, and it's difficult to answer in comments. Here is one suggestion: add `counter = 0;`  before the inner `for` loop. `String str = "aasdddr", result = ""; 
  int counter ;
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
      counter = 0;
      result += "" + str.charAt(i);`  . Your code will still not work, but that change should give you an idea for the next step.

Comment: thank you so much. I can't get used the concept of stack over flow for question. I hope it doesn't take long :(

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Thank you very much for your effort to reopen this question. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `counter` needs to be reset *inside* the `for` loop. Each time you encounter a character in the `source` String, you want to restart the counter. Otherwise, as you have seen, the value of the counter is strictly increasing.

Now, think about what happens if a character occurs in more than one place in the `source` String, as in the `"aasdddraabcdaa"` example. A sequence of 1 or more `a` appears in 3 places. Because, at the time you get to the 2nd occurrence of `a`, `a` has been previously counted, you want to skip over it.

Because the `source` String cannot contain digits, the `result` String can be used to check if a particular character value has already been processed. So, after fixing the problem with `counter`, the code can be fixed by adding these two lines:

```
 if (result.indexOf (source.charAt(i)) >= 0) { 
     continue; }
```

Here is the complete result:

```
package stackoverflowmisc;

public class StackOverflowMisc {
    
    public static String freqDist(String source) {
        String result = "";
        int counter ;  
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            if (result.indexOf (source.charAt(i)) >= 0) { continue; }
            counter = 1;
            result += source.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 1; j < source.length(); j++) {
                if (source.charAt(i) == source.charAt(j)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            result += counter;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] test = {"aasdddr", "aabacc", "aasdddraabcdaa"};
        
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println (test[i] + " - " + freqDist (test[i]));
        }
        System.out.println ("End of Program");
    }    
}
```

Run results:

```
aasdddr - a2s2d4r2
aabacc - a3b2c3
aasdddraabcdaa - a6s2d5r2b2c2
End of Program
```

In one of the Q&A comments, you said the source string can contain only letters. How would the program work if it were allowed to contain digits? You can't use the `result` String, because the processing inserts digits there. Again, this is an easy fix: Add a 3rd String to record which values have already been found:

```
public static String freqDist2(String source) {
        String result = "", found = "";
        int counter ;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {            
            if (found.indexOf (source.charAt(i)) >= 0) { continue; }
            counter = 1;
            result += source.charAt(i);
            found += source.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 1; j < source.length(); j++) {
                if (source.charAt(i) == source.charAt(j)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            result += counter;
        }
        return result;
}
```

Another possibility is to delete the corresponding characters from the `source` String as they are counted. If you are not allowed to modify the `Source` String, make a copy and use the copy.

Comment:  I don't know if this is what your professor or whomever had in mind by placing the "No array" restriction, because a `String` is essentially built on a `char` array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer. Probably this one is the most beautiful solution but you used some methods or statements that I haven't learned yet. Fortunately, I have solved this question after a long time. I will share my solution soon. Besides, If you accept, I want to get in contact with you as a junior.  It would be awful to have a friend like you. Again, thank you for everything.

Comment: *not awful, awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. But I think any question has more than one solution.
First, we should declare an empty string to keep the result. We use a nested loop because the outer loop will keep a character fixed during each iteration of the inner loop. Also, we should declare a count variable inside the outer loop. Because in each match, it will be increased by one and after controlling each character in the inner loop, it will be zero for the next check. Finally, after the inner loop, we should put a condition to check whether we have that character inside the result string. If there isn't any character like that, then it will be added to the result string. After that, its frequency (count) will be added. Outside of the loop, we can print it.

```
public class FrequenciesOfChar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "aabcccd"; // be sure that you don't have any digit in your string

    String result = ""; // this will hold new string

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { // this will hold a character till be checked by inner loop

        int count = 0; // put here so that it can be zero after each cycle for new character

        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) { // this will change

            if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)){ // this will check whether there is a same character

                count++; // if there is a same character, count will increase

            }

        }

        if( !(result.contains(""+str.charAt(i))) ){ // this checks if result doesn't contain the checked character
            result += ""+str.charAt(i); // first if result doesn't contain the checked character, character will be added
            result += count; // then the character's frequency will be added
        }

    }

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

}

Run Result:
aabcccd - a2b1c3d1

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check below solution:-
    String sentence = "aasdddraabcdaa";
    Arrays.stream(sentence.split(""))
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str ->str, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k,v) -> System.out.print(k+v));
```

Result : a6b1c1d4r1s1